# Play Framework application not available outside host

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

My application works on `localhost:9000` but even with `activator start`, the application isn't accessible from outside the host computer.  Say, over a local network.

I don't see anything in the logs other than a notification that the server started.  What do I need to do to make the application accessible from other machines?

Comment: Try `activator -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 start`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  No success from the other machine and still nothing in the logs.  The application still works from `localhost:9000`, though.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue. What OS are you using? Can you `telnet` on that port from other machines on the network?

Comment: telnet to `<host_ip>:9000` from other machines fails.  Ping to that IP does get through, however.

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  It certainly was a firewall issue.  If you want to leave an answer, I'll be happy to mark as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, play binds to `0.0.0.0`, making it accessible on all configured addresses and interfaces. If you want to explicitly bind it as such, you can start play using:

```
play -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 start
```

or

```
activator -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0 start
```

In case this doesn't resolve the issue, try to `telnet` to your host address on port 9000 from another machine. If you fail to get a connection, most likely the firewall on your host needs to be reconfigured to allow TCP access over port 9000.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some networking issues such as firewall or router port options are not enable. If you want to test it from outside you can try ngrok. Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) utility. First run your app check that its running on localhost. Then just go to command prompt and try ngrok portno. In your case it will be like ngrok 9000.  Ngrok will give you a url which will be working from outside.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

`play.filters.hosts.allowed += "."`

[font](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/host-not-allowed/6202)